# CAKEPHP: Linking the whole <div>

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a  having view of a specific field in Notes table.

```
    echo "<div id='notescover'>";
    echo "<p class='text'>"; 
    echo $viewnotes['Note']['notes']; 
    echo "</p>"; 
    echo "</div>";
```

And i have linked Comment to the specific note URL e.g /note/view/IDofNote

```
echo $this->Html->link('Comment', array( 'controller'=>'notes', 'action'=>'view',$viewnotes['Note']['id']), array('class'=> 'light_blue'));
```

I want to remove this link and link the same action to the above div tag. I was able to link the text inside the field like this

```
echo $this->Html->link($viewnotes['Note']['notes'], array( 'controller'=>'notes', 'action'=>'view',$viewnotes['Note']['id']), array('class'=> 'light_blue'));
```

but i want the whole box that  makes to be linked.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$text = '<p class="text">' . $viewnotes['Note']['notes'] . '</p>';
$div = $this->Html->div(null, $text, array('id' => 'notescover'));

echo $this->Html->link(
    $div, 
    array('controller' => 'notes', 'action' => 'view', $viewnotes['Note']['id']),
    array('class' => 'light_blue', 'escape' => false)
);
```

You could also compact it some more by doing this, if you prefer:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<div id="notescover"><p class="text">' . $viewnotes['Note']['notes'] . '</p></div>', 
    array('controller' => 'notes', 'action' => 'view', $viewnotes['Note']['id']),
    array('class' => 'light_blue', 'escape' => false)
);
```

You can put anything you like into the first parameter of `Html::link()`, but if you are adding markup in there, and not just plain text, it's important to include the `escape => false` attribute on the link, to avoid rendering the HTML special characters in your link as text.

Although, in my opinion, things like this become so convoluted when you use the Cake HTML helpers for anything that isn't simple, it's not even worth the time and effort to come up with code like this.  It also makes reading the code way more complicated than it needs to be, especially when you have to decipher the code later down the line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Link` or `URL` method inside `HtmlHelper` function

> Using **Link**

```php
$content = "<div id='notescover'>".
           "  <p class='text'>" . $viewnotes['Note']['notes'] . "</p>".
           "</div>";

echo $this->Html->link( $content, 
                        array( 'controller'=>'notes', 'action'=>'view', $viewnotes['Note']['id']), 
                        array('class'=> 'light_blue', 'escape' => false)
);
```

> Using **URL**

Adding the URL inside the HTML

```php
<a href="<?= $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'notes', 'action'=>'view', $viewnotes['Note']['id']), 
                              array('escape' => false)); ?>" 
  class="light_blue">
   <div id='notescover'>
      <p class='text'><?= $viewnotes['Note']['notes']; ?></p>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: html helper url method is valid only for cakephp 2, and you made answer for 8 year old question?

Comment: @Salines: Answering an old question will also help people who search the same issue. Projects with cakePhp2 are still active dude.